# How can I install dpkg-dev without installing gcc 4.6?

Tags: apt, dpkg, gcc

I have manually installed gcc/g++ 4.7 on my Ubuntu 12.04

When I run `sudo apt-get install dpkg-dev` it's trying to download and install g++ 4.6 which would obviously break 4.7.

How can I install dpkg-dev without installing gcc 4.6 ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [PPA](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them). One containing gcc/g++ 4.7 can be found [here](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-toolchain-r/+archive/test). The first link shows a graphical method of installing a PPA. Alternatively, via terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.7
```

Using a PPA to install gcc/g++ might allow apt-get to realise that gcc/g++ 4.7 satisfies the dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `apt-mark hold` is what I need.

If somebody knows more elegant method please let me know.